# How to get rid of gap on top of right column when left nav column is affix-top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first time using Bootstrap. There is a big gap on top of my col-sm-9 column always present before the left-side col-sm-3 nav is changed from `affix-top` to `affix` when the user moves past a small top banner.

I think all the features I have created this strange problem with my added css and js.  The page has a top nav bar that is affixed to the top also when the top banner is moved out of screen (when the user moves down the page). Finally, there is a scroll-spy on the left side nav.

I have Bootstrap version 3.2.0. **You can [see the code and the problem in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/563/).**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3" id="leftsidenav">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        ... <!-- this left-side nav is affixed and has scroll-spy -->
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9" id="rightcontent">
      This is the section that has a gap on top!
    </div>
  ...
```

No matter what I tried, I could not get rid of the gap on top of my col-sm-9. Can anyone help me out?

*Update:*

*Based on your initial responses, note that I would like the leftsidenav to stay affixed to the left side and rightcontent to its right side **even after the user scrolls down**. The reason I put in the margins and width is to prevent the leftsidenav completely getting covered by rightcontent after scrolling down.*

*Basically, you have to check scrolling down. This is the **[jsfiddle with my margin setting and gap problem](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/563/)**. Then compared to this is the **[jsfiddle without the margin setting but has the covering problem](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/564/)**.*

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/567/)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-left from your rightcontent div and add float property for right and left content like below.

```
#leftsidenav {
width:180px;
float:left
}
#rightcontent {
background-color: orange;
float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/552/)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work after you scroll down, please check the fiddles in my question update.

Comment: Remove the jquery code(only for leftnav code) from the demo link. Not sure what purpose you have used that one. It will work. http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/566/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your css that are interfering with the layout.

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/553/)

This includes the following updates.

**Removed widths and margins from the content/nav divs:**

```
#leftsidenav {
    /*width:180px;  <-- deleted */
}

#rightcontent {
    background-color: orange;
    /*margin-left: 200px; <-- deleted */
}
```

You are using bootstrap columns to define the layout, so by adding widths you're overriding the default layout.

**Added classes to the content divs to help them render in different sized windows:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3" id="leftsidenav">

<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 col-lg-9" id="rightcontent">
```

These classes are designed to be added to the containers to tell them how you want them to render when the window is: `lg` - large, `sm` - small, `xs` - extra small. So this defines that you want 3 columns (25%) of width for the left nav and 9 columns (75%) of width for the content.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work after you scroll down, please check the fiddles in my question update.